# Delete/Close own question after a period of time

Tags: feature-request

It would be a nice-to-have feature to be able to delete/close your own question if its not answered with an acceptable answer for some period of time and you are no longer looking for an answer.

Comment: You can always flag it for moderator attention and if it's really fit for deletion it will get deleted. IMO once asked, question should stay in place.

Comment: Depends why are you no longer looking for an answer - if it's because you've *found* an answer yourself, then you could self-answer your own question so it might help someone else in the future.

Comment: @DMA57361: Its when a user hasn't found an answer and just wants to close/delete the question. Maybe an additional status can be introduced, something that specifies that the owner closed it as its been quite some time since it was opened and they are no longer looking for an answer.